# What's the difference of passing a class as a normal parameter and by reference?

Tags: c#, ref

Take for example a simple method:

```
public string GetDisplayName(string username, IUserService UserService)
{
    var user = UserService.GetUserByUsername(username);
    return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} ({3})", user.Title, user.FirstName, user.LastName, username);
}
```

So UserService is a class, and by definition in C#, a class is a reference type.

If I were to do the following:

```
public string GetDisplayName(string username, ref IUserService UserService)
{
    var user = UserService.GetUserByUsername(username);
    return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} ({3})", user.Title, user.FirstName, user.LastName, username);
}
```

What are the main differences here?

Comment: ByRef just points to the object (so useful in subs when you want to populate a property for example), ByVal copies the object so that it is a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific example, there is no difference because you are not assigning anything to the parameter `UserService`.

However, if you were to assign a new instance to the `UserService` parameter, that would change the object referenced by *caller* of that method.

Here's a sample program to demonstrate the difference:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Demo
    {
        public int Value;

        public Demo(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void test1(Demo demo)
        {
            demo = new Demo(42);
        }

        private static void test2(ref Demo demo)
        {
            demo = new Demo(42);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            Demo demo1 = new Demo(0);
            Demo demo2 = demo1; // demo2 references demo1.

            // Calling test1() will NOT change the object referenced by demo1:

            test1(demo1);

            Console.WriteLine(demo1.Value); // Prints 0
            demo2.Value = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(demo1.Value); // Prints 1, indicating that changing demo2 also changed demo1

            // Calling test2() will cause demo1 to reference a DIFFERENT instance of class Demo:

            test2(ref demo1);

            Console.WriteLine(demo1.Value); // Prints 42, indicating that demo1 was changed.
            demo2.Value = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(demo1.Value); // Prints 42, indicating that changing demo2 no longer changes demo1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The differences are:

- The method with the `ref` parameter needs to be called with a variable for that parameter. If you for example would use `new CompanyUserService()` to create the user service for the call, you would need to put that in a variable and use the variable in the call instead of just passing on the newly created reference.
- Inside the method with the `ref` parameter, the value of the variable used in the call can be changed. In the other method the parameter is a copy of the value, so changing the value of the parameter variable inside the method will not affect anything outside the method.
- Parameters with the `ref` keyword are sent as pointers to the variable containing the value instead of the value itself, so whenever you use the parameter in the method there is another step of redirection.

(The last point is not dictated by the specifications, but that is how the actual implementations handle the `ref` parameters. The specifications only state how the parameters should work, not how it should be implemented.)

Comment: Don't list implementation details, and also 2 is wrong for reference types.